# How to decrypt files using CipherInputStream or why the following methods don't work

Tags: java, encryption

I have the following function to encrypt files. I printed the result of both files and everything seems to work properly.

The encrypted file is changed and is the same length then the input file.

```
public void encrypt(String password, String filePath){
    InputStream is = null;
    OutputStream os = null;
    CipherOutputStream cos = null;
    try {
        is = new FileInputStream(new File(filePath));
        os = new FileOutputStream(new File(filePath + ".enc"));
        char[] passwordChars = password.toCharArray();
        SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
        KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(passwordChars, salt, 1024, 256);
        SecretKey tmp = factory.generateSecret(spec);
        SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec(tmp.getEncoded(), "AES");
        Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, iv);
        cos = new CipherOutputStream(os, c);
        byte[] b = new byte[1024];
        while(is.read(b) != -1)
            cos.write(b);
            b = new byte[1024];
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (os != null)
                os.close();
            if (is != null)
                is.close();
            if (cos != null)
                cos.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {

        }
    }
}
```

The problem happens when I try to decrypt the file afterwards. I use CipherInputStream with the following function:

```
public void decrypt(String password, String filePath){   
    InputStream is = null;
    OutputStream os = null;
    CipherInputStream cis = null;
    try {
        is = new FileInputStream(new File(filePath));
        os = new FileOutputStream(new File(filePath + ".dec"));
        char[] passwordChars = password.toCharArray();
        SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
        KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(passwordChars, salt, 1024, 256);
        SecretKey tmp = factory.generateSecret(spec);
        SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec(tmp.getEncoded(), "AES");
        Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, iv);
        cis = new CipherInputStream(is, c);
        byte[] b = new byte[1024];
        while(cis.read(b) != -1){
            os.write(b);
            b = new byte[1024];
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (os != null)
                os.close();
            if (is != null)
                is.close();
            if (cis != null)
                cis.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {

        }
    }
}
```

The while loop is not entered at all. It acts like the file is empty while I verified and it is clearly not. Encryption seems to work properly but not decryption.

I tried changing the function to use CipherOutputStream but then the same thing happens. I get a decrypted file of length 0.

Why is the decrypt method not working?

Comment: in your decryption youre using "cos" instead of cis and cis would be null?

Comment: Sorry thats a mistake because I modified the function on Stack Overflow before I posted. The question still holds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many things to be fixed

> c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, iv);

Where is IV defined? If it's static, using cbc mode you break the security almost completely.

Next - you are using CBC mode without any authentication (hmac), try to search for "malleable cipher"

> Why is the decrypt method not working?

```
byte[] b = new byte[1024];
    while(is.read(b) != -1)
        cos.write(b);
        b = new byte[1024];
    }
```

**This is completely wrong**. You are writing a full array `b` of 1024 bytes regardless of read input. (is there a reason to recreate the array in the loop?)

try something like

```
b=byte[1024];
for(int bytesRead=in.read(b); bytesRead>-1; bytesRead=in.read(b))
   cos.write(b, 0, bytesRead);
 cos.flush()
```

the same is valid for decryption, please fix this first and then try to debug your app

Note:  I'm not really fond of the CipherStream implementation, I'd suggest you to use `cipher.update` and `cipher.doFinal`

Comment: +1 Agree with your answer - interested about your final remark around preferring `cipher.update` etc. - what do you not like about the CipherStream stuff?

Comment: @luke-joshua-park maybe it's just my bad experience how some developers around me (mis)use the cipherstreams, mainly when trying to combine multiple inputs (iv, ciphertext, hmac), even imho the intention is make the I/O simpler. Maybe I could skip the comment, but it's my preference, really nothing very specific

Comment: Thanks for explaining - I agree with you really - my general rule is to only use `CipherOutputStream` if you *actually need* streaming.